# Unable to pass arguments to a .jmx files from build.gradle file through jmRun

Tags: gradle, jmeter, build.gradle, gradlew

i am facing multiple problems with my .jmx file.

I am working with bzm-concurrency thread group

1) it is not recognising the standard format of passing the user defined values
like: ${__P(SERVER_NAME,localhost)} instead of passing "localhost" to my script it is appending "${__P(SERVER_NAME,localhost)}" to my url.

After passing only the value i.e (localhost) it is working fine

2) Also, iam running my jmeter script from build.gradle file and iam unable to pass the url and other details from them

|SERVER_NAME|${__P(SERVER_NAME,localhost)}|  --> this code is not working
|SERVER_NAME|localhost| --> this code is working fine

```
jmeter {
jmTestFiles = [file("src/main/Jmetrscript.jmx")]
jmSystemPropertiesFiles= [file(path of my properties file)] //to add additional system properties

jmUserProperties = ["SERVER_NAME ="+System.getProperty('SERVER_NAME','localhost'), "SERVER_PORT ="+System.getProperty('SERVER_PORT','9080') ]

enableExtendedReports = true //produce Graphical and CSV reports
```

}

when i run this using gradlew jmRun -DSERVER_NAME=localhost it is not passing the value.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Gradle Plugin - Advanced Usage](https://github.com/jmeter-gradle-plugin/jmeter-gradle-plugin/wiki/Advanced-Usage)

> Supported JMeter commandline arguments ([see full list here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)):
>
> ```
> -p, --propfile {argument}, the jmeter property file to use
> -q, --addprop {argument}, additional property file(s)
> -t, --testfile {argument}, the jmeter test(.jmx) file to run
> -J, --jmeterproperty {argument}={value}, Define additional JMeter properties
> -D, --systemproperty {argument}={value}, Define additional System properties
> -S, --systemPropertyFile {filename}, a property file to be added as System properties
> -r, --runremote (non-GUI only), Start remote servers (as defined by the jmeter property remote_hosts)
> -G, --globalproperty (argument)[=(value)], Define Global properties (sent to servers), e.g. -Gport=123,  or -Gglobal.properties
> ```

So you should pass JMeter Properties via `-J` command-line argument like:

```
jmRun -JSERVER_NAME=localhost etc
```

References:

- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: it is not working. Displaying the following error    Unknown command-line option '-J'.

Comment: What is your gradle plugin version?

Comment: iam using gradle.plugin.net.foragerr.jmeter:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.1.0-4.0 and my gradle version is distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip